# Where do I get the Firefox global menu extension?

Tags: firefox, globalmenu

I switched to using the beta channel for Firefox recently. I don't have the extension allowing Firefox to use the global menu, and I'm not sure where to find it. What do I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an extension called firefox-globalmenu. It's available in the software-center

Via the termimal:

sudo apt-get install firefox-globalmenu